Flutter: ios configuration ignores every way of setting up the target platform version
I am currently trying to make flutter_google_maps work. I am developing on Windows and the ios-build is done by Codemagic. Everything went fine until now. The problem: flutter_google_maps requires ios version 14, whereas the default version of my current flutter instance seems to be 12.0. And no matter what I am telling it, it doesn't seem to accept version 14.0 as the desired version. When building the app I always receive:
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'workmanager' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 14.0.
which is weird, because workmanager compiled just fine before I put flutter_google_maps to the pubspec.yaml. But anyway...
In the Podfile, I already set up:
platform :ios, '14.0'
and
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end

I also added
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>14.0</string>

to the AppFrameworkInfo.plist. Nothing helps.
Now I am running out of ideas...
Anyone who has an advice?
